# Execute OS Command from Painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a way to execute an underlying bash command from an Elasticsearch painless script?

I'm looking to run a non interactive command when the script executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you cannot do this, it's not allowed due to potential security risks